# 2.8 - Bevel is not "always" working

Tags: bevel

i know there are already threads about issues with this and this and this side of some work. 
But most of them relate to mesh topology issues, obvious issues like unwelded vertices etc.

To me though in this example all seems fine. But somehow it is really messing up my flow.

Any ideas on WHY it is happening? I mean sure, maybe a bug, maybe me. But I would love to know if there is maybe a different approach to this?

I transition currently from 3ds max to blender ;)

Thanks for your help.[Here is a video of the issue](https://youtu.be/l-2vEavOnDE)

[image]

Comment: Have you applied the scale of the object? Do you have extra vertices? Do you mind sharing your blender file?

Comment: Select all, remove doubles?

Comment: Hey there, yo applied it all, no re-scaling or so. super weird. I did fixed the issue with re-modelling that part but that did of course not solve it.

Comment: I checked for double vertices, lonely edges, un attached stuff and also if there double faces or so. Super weird